# Realm access from incorrect thread on compositeDisposable clear

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I am adding all my observer that are subscribed in an activity are added to CompositeDisposable. 
OnStop of activity is calling mCompositeDisposable.clear() which creates below crash log.
As CompositeDisposable.clear calls onDispose please find below code does to realm

```
Single.create(...).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                   .subscribe(observer);
mCompositeDisposable.add(observer);
```

creats realm here in Schedulers.io()

```
Single<RealmList<T>> source ...
source .doOnDispose(() -> {
 if (mRealm == null) {
            return;
        }
 if (Looper.myLooper() != null) {
            mRealm.removeAllChangeListeners();
        }
 if (!mRealm.isClosed()) {
            mRealm.close();
        }
mRealm = null;
}
```

Giving the below crash logs

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread.**

```
Realm access from incorrect thread.
 Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
                                                       at io.realm.BaseRealm.JN(SourceFile:438)
                                                       at io.realm.BaseRealm.removeAllListeners(SourceFile:263)
                                                       at io.realm.Realm.removeAllChangeListeners(SourceFile:1399)
...

 at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnDispose$DoOnDisposeObserver.dispose(SourceFile:60)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.dispose(SourceFile:85)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.aq(SourceFile:124)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.dispose(SourceFile:78)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.aq(SourceFile:124)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.dispose(SourceFile:78)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.aq(SourceFile:124)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.dispose(SourceFile:87)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.aq(SourceFile:124)
                                                       at io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver.dispose(SourceFile:91)
                                                       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.a(SourceFile:240)
                                                       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.clear(SourceFile:206)
```

Tried with .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) but didnt worked

Comment: If you want to run Realm queries on a background thread, you need to create a HandlerThread, and use its looper with `AndroidSchedulers.from(looper)` to create a scheduler on which you can run Realm queries. After that, you can map to non-managed RealmObjects that can be observed on UI thread. You can find an example for this [***here***](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/22e076b6eff18b539d9dd9991c822c35e09d18bd/simple-stack-example-mvp-fragments/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemoexamplefragments/data/repository/TaskRepository.kt#L30).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> creats realm here in Schedulers.io()

You're creating instance of Realm in `mainThread` then asking Realm to operate (e.g. load data) in `io` thread which is impossible in Realm by design. Example by developers of Realm states few points to keep in mind here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/rxJavaExample.

Implementing 1st and 4th points into your code snippet we will get us proper solution. Note that method `findAllAsync()` will do everything asynchronously for you no need to create `io` thread by using RxJava

```
    Single<RealmList<T>> realmResults = realm.where(....)
                .equalTo(...)
                .findAllAsync()
                .asFlowable()
                .map { realmResult->
                    val realmList = RealmList<T>()
                    realmList.addAll(realmResult.toList())
                    return realmList
                }
                .firstOrError()

            realm.close()
```